# JAX-WS client and SocketTimeoutException vs ConnectException

Tags: java, jboss, jax-ws

I have to call a web service that takes 40 seconds to respond. I'm in JBoss-EAP 6.4 and I use this code:

```
IService svc = service.getBasicHttpBindingIService();
[...]
((BindingProvider) svc).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout",timeout)
[...]
svc.processMessage(req);
```

When the timeout is less then 20000 (20 seconds), I get the expected exception:

```
HTTP transport error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

If the timeout is bigger than 20000, i get another exeption after 20 second:

```
HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

So, I can't get the response from the server (40 seconds to respond), I always get the exception. What kind of timeout I have to increase?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want the timeout to be 40 seconds? There are two timeouts represented by "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout" and "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout". You could have been connected to the server, but the request is taking long to process in which case, the latter setting would take effect. Note: I believe these settings are for JBoss (I could be wrong, cross check it).

Comment: I need a timeout greater than 40 seconds cause the service thakes 40 seconds to reply. I tried with all these settings but it doesn't works, I always get the ConnectException:
javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout,
javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout,
javax.xml.ws.connect.timeout,
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout,
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout,
com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout,
org.jboss.ws.timeout